# Getting Error on server : "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Tags: c#

I'm go for the fetch data using by id in c# using web api angularjs. but this code it's in my locally working very well and on server getting error like this 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.' any one know how can fix it this is error.here below listed my method in c#.

This is my api method :

```
 var ProItemList = db.Promotion_ctc.Where(x => x.pid == Pro.id)
 .Select(i => new ProductItemViewModel
  {
   ItemId = i.ItemId,
    ProductId = i.ProductId,
    Qty = i.Qty,
     Rate = i.Rate,
     Date = i.Date
   })
   .ToList();

         ProItemList.ForEach(s =>
            {
                s.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(s.Date).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");                    
            });

    var Details = new
    {
      Pro.id,
      Pro.name,
     Pro.image_url,
      ProItemList 
 };

  return Json(new { data = Details });            
 }
```

in my database and class Date filed datatype is string. so any one know how can resolved this issue.

Comment: You should use `DateTime.ParseExact`

Comment: where n how can used give me some hint

Comment: What is you date structure in the db?

Comment: Also, why cant you use datetime as your db datatype?

Comment: in my db like this date "21/04/2017",dd/MM/yyyy format store. and i need string so i m take string datatype

Comment: can you please tell me DateTime.ParseExact where is used n how?please

Comment: Why are you storing dates as strings in your database at all?

Answer (score 0):

If there's no way for you to change the datatype in your db to date then, You should use `DateTime.ParseExact` instead of using `Convert.ToDateTime`

In your case:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(s.Date,"dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**Update**

Once you've got a `DateTime` (whether its by using the above or preferably changing the type in the db, you can get a string in any format you'd like.
For example:

```
dateTime.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

If you've changed your data type then your linq would be simpler:

```
Select(i => new ProductItemViewModel
{
    ItemId = i.ItemId,
    ProductId = i.ProductId,
    Qty = i.Qty,
    Rate = i.Rate,
    Date = i.Date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
})
.ToList();
```

And you can get rid of this:

```
ProItemList.ForEach(s =>
{
    s.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(s.Date).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");                    
});
```

Comment: now i m getting error in local String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. using with your wave.

Comment: So obviously, the `s.Date` is not in the structure you have mentioned. this -> `var d = DateTime.ParseExact("21/04/2017", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` will work. Carefuly check the date structure.

Comment: But it is far better to use the proper dbtype!

Comment: ok now i m change the datatype both side class and in db as datetime so now i want to get date in this format so how can do? "MM-dd-yyyy"

Comment: As you did before `yourDateField.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")`

Comment: so now in my db store date like this "2017-04-20 18:30:00.000"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141759/discussion-between-coderwill-and-ofir-winegarten).